# Windows 2012 Datacenter in-place upgrade to windows 2016 Datacenter

Tags: upgrade, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

As Azure does not support in-place upgrade from windows 2012 datacenter to windows 2016 datacenter, I was forced to to download a vhd from Azure blob(more than a week, 127 gb file), but it turned out that the publicly available iso of 2016 datacenter is the evolution version, and it can't be used to perform the in-place upgrade, I wonder if you can help to find a legal way to find the proper iso of windows 2016 datacenter to perform in-place upgrade.

Comment: This isn’t something we will be able to help you with.

Comment: I am new to microsoft world, I wonder if someone knows what is the legal process of getting the proper iso.

Comment: You download the ISO from the Microsoft website, but that requires you have a license, to [Windows 3016 DataCenter](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/in-place-system-upgrade), they do not support in-place upgrades for **any** Windows-based VMs. Their suggestion in the documentation is to create a new VM with the desired OS (in your case, Windows Server 2016) and then migrate the workload. No doubt, this would likely be the faster alternative for you if it took you a week to download a 127 GB file.

However, if you really, *really* don't want to do that, then your only alternative is to download your Windows Server 2012 VM's VHD and then upgrade it to Windows Server 2016 on your own, then upload the new VHD back to Azure (which should allow it to [automatically activate through their KMS system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-activation-problems), so not having a product key isn't an issue), but again, sounds like you have slow internet so that could take weeks. I would just bite the bullet, create a new Windows Server 2016 VM, and get to work on moving your services to the new VM.

Comment: moving the workload is not an option. I created a local vm with the download vhd, but couldn't find a proper iso of 2016 datacenter. The public one is the evaluation iso, and that doesn't work, and that is documented.

Comment: @EdikMkoyan So you are saying the evaluation ISO refuses to perform an upgrade? You can only do a fresh install with the evaluation ISO?

Comment: yes, and I need the proper iso.

Comment: Then what you are asking for is a copy of the retail ISO for Windows Server 2016 As that is copyrighted material, we cannot help you try to obtain that material. That is why I was trying to offer you an alternative (migrating the workload). If migrating the workload is absolutely out of the question, then the only legal recourse is to purchase a legal copy of Server 2016 or stay on Server 2012. It wouldn't hurt to contact Microsoft and explain this issue to them, and see if they can help with an ISO, though. I doubt they'd be much help, however.

Comment: trust me you help much more, we have dozens of 2016 servers in our azure subscription, I am sure we have the license. But it is damn hard to find that.